# Query trans log or tempdb?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

New DBA, all of our databases are SQL 2005.  All of our servers run in Simple recovery mode.  I work for a school district, where we report student attendance to the state.

I run a query to fix reporting minutes on a specific grade level of students.  I have this scheduled as a job to run daily.

Our vendor is now saying that this is fixed in their product, but we believe it is fixed because we run the script daily.

Is there something that I can query to find out how many records were affected when the job is run?  I would need to do this for a date in the past (May 26, 2015).

Here is the script I run daily -

```
/*
The default absFTE value for students using twice daily attendance is 0.50.

This Query is used to change the absFTE values from 0.50 to 1.0 for PS students that are only 
half day in order to send the full days worth of minutes.

*/

Update rev.EPC_STU_ATT_DAILY
Set ABS_FTE1 = '1.00'
Where DAILY_ATTEND_GU IN
(
Select 
da.DAILY_ATTEND_GU
from rev.EPC_STU_ATT_DAILY da 
join rev.EPC_STU_ENROLL en on da.ENROLLMENT_GU = en.ENROLLMENT_GU
join rev.EPC_STU_SCH_YR ssy on en.STUDENT_SCHOOL_YEAR_GU = ssy.STUDENT_SCHOOL_YEAR_GU
join rev.EPC_STU st on st.STUDENT_GU = ssy.STUDENT_GU
join rev.REV_ORGANIZATION_YEAR oyr on (oyr.ORGANIZATION_YEAR_GU = ssy.ORGANIZATION_YEAR_GU)
join rev.REV_ORGANIZATION org on (org.ORGANIZATION_GU = oyr.ORGANIZATION_GU)
join rev.EPC_SCH s on s.ORGANIZATION_GU = org.ORGANIZATION_GU
join rev.REV_YEAR y on y.YEAR_GU = oyr.YEAR_GU
join rev.SIF_22_Common_CurrentYear cy on cy.SCHOOL_YEAR = y.SCHOOL_YEAR
left join rev.REV_BOD_LOOKUP_VALUES grade on grade.VALUE_CODE=ssy.GRADE
      and grade.LOOKUP_DEF_GU=
      (
      select LOOKUP_DEF_GU 
       from rev.REV_BOD_LOOKUP_DEF 
       where LOOKUP_DEF_CODE='grade'
      )
Where da.ABS_FTE1 is not null and VALUE_DESCRIPTION IN ('PS')
)

Update rev.EPC_STU_ATT_DAILY
Set ABS_FTE2 = '1.00'
Where DAILY_ATTEND_GU IN
(
Select 
da.DAILY_ATTEND_GU
from rev.EPC_STU_ATT_DAILY da 
join rev.EPC_STU_ENROLL en on da.ENROLLMENT_GU = en.ENROLLMENT_GU
join rev.EPC_STU_SCH_YR ssy on en.STUDENT_SCHOOL_YEAR_GU = ssy.STUDENT_SCHOOL_YEAR_GU
join rev.EPC_STU st on st.STUDENT_GU = ssy.STUDENT_GU
join rev.REV_ORGANIZATION_YEAR oyr on (oyr.ORGANIZATION_YEAR_GU = ssy.ORGANIZATION_YEAR_GU)
join rev.REV_ORGANIZATION org on (org.ORGANIZATION_GU = oyr.ORGANIZATION_GU)
join rev.EPC_SCH s on s.ORGANIZATION_GU = org.ORGANIZATION_GU
join rev.REV_YEAR y on y.YEAR_GU = oyr.YEAR_GU
join rev.SIF_22_Common_CurrentYear cy on cy.SCHOOL_YEAR = y.SCHOOL_YEAR
left join rev.REV_BOD_LOOKUP_VALUES grade on grade.VALUE_CODE=ssy.GRADE
      and grade.LOOKUP_DEF_GU=
      (
      select LOOKUP_DEF_GU 
       from rev.REV_BOD_LOOKUP_DEF 
       where LOOKUP_DEF_CODE='grade'
      )
Where da.ABS_FTE2 is not null and VALUE_DESCRIPTION IN ('PS')
)
```

Comment: Unless you have some way to track it `LAST_CHANGED_DATE` or CDC or server side trace running ..NO.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the output clause at the end of each update statement with a COUNT(inserted.*) the counts of updated records will be returned as a result set.

You could create a new table in a new database to store the results from your scheduled script or have the SQL Agent output the results to a file.

Have a look at this answer for help with OUTPUT clause [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999396/how-do-i-use-an-insert-statements-output-clause-to-get-the-identity-value)

Comment: Just to clarify, do you really mean adding `OUTPUT COUNT(inserted.*)` to an UPDATE statement? I never tried using COUNT in an OUTPUT clause before but I've just tried it and received `Msg 158, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
An aggregate may not appear in the OUTPUT clause.`

Comment: Yeah looks like I missed the intermediate step of inserting the output into a temp table and then running COUNT on that. Good spot. I'll update in a bit.